# gst-launch-0.10 no syncronized audio with alsa and hdmi

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch, gstreamer-0.10

I'm working on a imx 6DualLite.

**I can't add or edit system libraries.**

I have to play an audio file from hdmi and speakers.

This is the pipeline I am using:

```sh
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/home/root/beep.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! tee name=t ! queue ! alsasink t. ! queue ! volume volume=1 ! alsasink device=sysdefault:CARD=imxhdmisoc
```

The problem is that the audio of the speakers is not synchronized with the audio of the hdmi

I've already tried to add

```
... alsasink device=sysdefault:CARD=imxhdmisoc sync=TRUE
```

Comment: This depends on the HDMI device's latency. This info is not known to GStreamer so it would be pure luck if it could synchronize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (in my case it worked) by linking the two cards that are displayed with the command:

```sh
~ $ cat / proc / asound / cards
  0 [DWHDMI]: dw-hdmi-ahb-aud - DW-HDMI
                       DW-HDMI rev 0x0a, irq 22
  1 [sgtl5000audio]: sgtl5000-audio - sgtl5000-audio
                       sgtl5000-audio
  2 [tda1997xaudio]: tda1997x-audio - tda1997x-audio
                       tda1997x-audio
```

By following this guide:
https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc#Virtual_multi_channel_devices

I edited the file `/etc/asound.conf`. I do not quote the whole file (it is very long) but only the last part that I modified:

```
...

pcm.!default{
type plug
route_policy "average"
slave.pcm "asymed"
}

ctl.!default{
type hw
card 0
}

ctl.mixer0{
type hw
card 0
}
```

became

```
...

pcm.!default{
type plug
route_policy "average"
slave.pcm "asymed"
}

ctl.mixer0{
type hw
card 0
}

pcm.primary{
        type hw
        card 0
        device 0
}

ctl.primary {
  type hw
  card 0
}

pcm.secondary{
        type hw
        card 1
        device 0
}

ctl.secondary {
  type hw
  card 1
}

pcm.multi {
  type multi
  slaves.a.pcm "primary"
  slaves.a.channels 2
  slaves.b.pcm "secondary"
  slaves.b.channels 2
  bindings.0.slave a
  bindings.0.channel 0
  bindings.1.slave a
  bindings.1.channel 1
  bindings.2.slave b
  bindings.2.channel 0
  bindings.3.slave b
  bindings.3.channel 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Florian mentioned, I'm not sure you'll realistically be able to expect the outputs to be synchronized automatically.

But if you don't mind some user intervention and/or hard-coding, you could experiment with the `render-delay` property of each alsasink.  Set the value in nanoseconds.  (e.g. one second is 1000000000 nanos).

Here's a sample with video:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! videoconvert ! tee name=t ! queue ! ximagesink t. ! queue ! ximagesink render-delay=1000000000`